# Scraping paginated web table with python pandas & beautifulSoup

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I am a beginner in python pandas, i am trying to scrap a paginated table using beautiful soup package, the data is scraped, but the content of each cell comes in a single row, i couldn't get a coherent csv file

here is my code :

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

file=open(os.path.expanduser("sites_commerciaux.csv"), "wb")

def make_soup(url):
    thepage=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata=BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    return soupdata


headers="Nom_commercial_du_Site,Ville,Etat,Surface_GLA,Nombre_de_boutique,Contact"
file.write(bytes(headers,encoding='ascii',errors='ignore'))
save=""
for num in range(0,22): 
    soup=make_soup("http://www.ceetrus.com/fr/implantations-sites-commerciaux?page="+str(num))
    for rec in soup.findAll('tr'):
        saverec=""
        for data in rec.findAll('td'):
            saverec=saverec+","+data.text
            if len(saverec)!=0:
             save=save+"\n"+saverec[1:]

file.write(bytes(save,encoding='ascii',errors='ignore'))
```

can anyone help me fix it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i did some cleaning. first, why the bytes type? you're writing text. then why ascii? please use unicode. if later in your code you really need ascii encode to ascii then. the use of `findAll` is deprecated, please use `find_all`. you had also a possible issue with commas in the surface value. finally, always use context managers when possible (here: working with files)

and now for your question, you had two problems:

1. your test `if len(saverec)!=0:` was in the for-loop, generating lots
   of useless data.
2. you were not stripping the data of its unneeded whitespaces

.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os


def make_soup(url):
    thepage=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata=BeautifulSoup(thepage,"html.parser")
    return soupdata


save=""
for num in range(0, 22):
    soup=make_soup("http://www.ceetrus.com/fr/implantations-sites-commerciaux?page="+str(num))
    for rec in soup.find_all('tr'):
        saverec=""
        for data in rec.find_all('td'):
            data = data.text.strip()
            if "," in data:
                data = data.replace(",", "")
            saverec=saverec+","+data
        if len(saverec)!=0:
         save=save+"\n"+saverec[1:]
    print('#%d done' % num)

headers="Nom_commercial_du_Site,Ville,Etat,Surface_GLA,Nombre_de_boutique,Contact"
with open(os.path.expanduser("sites_commerciaux.csv"), "w") as csv_file:
    csv_file.write(headers)
    csv_file.write(save)
```

which outputs for the first page:

```
Nom_commercial_du_Site,Ville,Etat,Surface_GLA,Nombre_de_boutique,Contact
ALCORCÓN,ALCORCÓN - MADRID,Ouvert,4298 m²,40,José Carlos GARCIA
Alegro Alfragide,CARNAXIDE,Ouvert,11461 m²,122,
Alegro Castelo Branco,CASTELO BRANCO,Ouvert,6830 m²,55,
Alegro Setúbal,Setúbal,Ouvert,27000 m²,114,
Ancona,Ancona,Ouvert,7644 m²,41,Ettore PAPPONETTI
Angoulême La Couronne,LA COURONNE,Ouvert,6141 m²,45,Juliette GALLOUEDEC
Annecy Grand Epagny,EPAGNY,Ouvert,20808 m²,61,Delphine BENISTY
Anping,Tainan,Ouvert,969 m²,21,Roman LEE
АКВАРЕЛЬ,Volgograd,Ouvert,94025 m²,182,Viktoria ZAITSEVA
Arras,ARRAS,Ouvert,4000 m²,26,Anais NIZON
```

Comment: Thank you very much @bobrobbob, i just added "encoding="utf-16" and i got all the data well organized in the csv file.
can you email me please ? : tc.nada@yahoo.fr

Comment: @NadaTc That's not how Stack Overflow works. We're not here to fix your code, nor privately help you do so.

Comment: Also to @bobrobbob, please practice proper use of grammar in your Stack Overflow questions and answers. Is your shift key broken...?